# Angular view not updating on sockets

Tags: angularjs, node.js, model-view-controller, socket.io, mean-stack

I am developing a module of chat application using sockets in Mean Stack. However my view in angular is not updating properly. My console logs are getting fine and even the view gets something but it's not being updated properly like it should

**html:**

```
<div class="conversation-wrap col-lg-3">
    <dummyTag ng-repeat="thread in message">
        <div class="media conversation" ng-if="thread.sender._id !== currentUserId">
            <a class="pull-left">
                <img class="media-object" ng-src="{{thread.sender.profileImageURL}}" data-ng-class="{'active' : $index=== selected}" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;">
            </a>
            <a href="#" ng-click="selectedThread(thread)">
                <div class="media-body">
                    <h5 class="media-heading">{{thread.sender.displayName}}</h5>
                    <small ng-repeat="messageDetails in thread.messages">{{messageDetails.messageBody | limitTo:1}}</small>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="media conversation" ng-if="thread.sender._id == currentUserId">
            <a class="pull-left">
                <img class="media-object" ng-src="{{thread.receiver.profileImageURL}}" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;">
            </a>
            <a href="#" ng-click="selectedThread($index)">
                <div class="media-body">
                    <h5 class="media-heading">{{thread.receiver.displayName}}</h5>
                    <!--                                 <small ng-repeat="messageDetails in thread.messages">{{messageDetails.messageBody | limitTo:1}}</small>
 --></div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </dummyTag>
</div>
<div class="message-wrap col-lg-8">
    <div class="msg-wrap">
        <div class="alert alert-info msg-date">
            <strong>Today</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="media msg" ng-repeat="message in message.messages">
            <a class="pull-left" href="#">
                <img class="media-object" ng-src="{{message.author.profileImageURL}}" style="width: 32px; height: 32px;">
            </a>
            <div class="media-body">
                <small class="pull-right time"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 12:10am</small>
                <h5 class="media-heading">{{message.author.displayName}}</h5>
                <small class="col-lg-10">{{message.messageBody}}</small>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**controller:**

```
'use strict';

// Create the 'chat' controller
angular.module('chat').controller('MessageInboxController', ['$scope', '$location', 'Authentication', 'Socket', '$http', '$modal',
    function($scope, $location, Authentication, Socket, $http, $modal) {

        $scope.message = [];
        $scope.text = {};

        $scope.LoadInitialData = function() {
            //Method Call to Get Users on Team
            $http.get('/api/teamsByUser').success(function(response) {
                $scope.AllTeams = response;
            });

            //Get All Threads on User
            $http.get('/api/users/me').then(function(response) {
                $scope.currentUserId = response.data._id;
                $http.get('/api/GetAllThreads').then(function(response) {
                    $scope.message = response.data;
                    console.log($scope.message);
                });
            }); //users/me then ending here
        };



        //On Socket message on update converstation
        Socket.on('UpdateConversation', function(message) {
            console.log(message);
            console.log($scope.message);
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.message.length; i++) {

                if ($scope.message[i]._id === message._id) {
                    $scope.message[i].messages.push(message.messages);
                }
            }
        });


        $scope.selectedThread = function(index) {
            $scope.threadData = index;
            $scope.message.messages = $scope.message[index].messages;
            console.log($scope.message.messages);
            // return index;

        };

        //Method to update thread. That is send a new message
        $scope.UpdateThread = function() {
            console.log("Getting Here");

            if ($scope.currentUserId === $scope.message[$scope.threadData].sender._id) {
                Socket.emit('UpdateThread', {
                    sendTo: $scope.message[$scope.threadData].receiver,
                    messageBody: $scope.text.messageBody
                });
            } else {
                Socket.emit('UpdateThread', {
                    sendTo: $scope.message[$scope.threadData].sender,
                    messageBody: $scope.text.messageBody
                });
            }
            $scope.text = '';

        };


        //Modal Method to Create a New Message
        $scope.NewMessage = function() {

            var modalInstance;

            modalInstance = $modal.open({
                templateUrl: 'modules/chat/client/views/partials/NewMessage.client.view.html',
                backdrop: true,
                controller: 'NewMessageController',
                size: 'md',
                resolve: {
                    team: function() {
                        return $scope.AllTeams;
                    }
                }
            });
            modalInstance.result.then(function(result) {
                // $scope.message = result;
                // if($scope.message.receiverId === $scope.currentuserId){
                //  $scope.message.receiverId = result.sender;
                // }
            }, function() {

            });
        };
}
]);
```

[image]
    This is how my view gets updated when socket on is triggered**(blank image and no message. However if I reload the page I get the message properly because in ng-init I am getting all the messages from database)**. At first I thought it might be something because of the angular digest cycle. I tried with $scope.$apply as well. Still the same result. I am pretty sure this has something do with my ng repeats. Any sort of help would be appreciated!

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUJH3.png
```

Comment: shouldn't you be doing concat like `$scope.message[i].messages.concat(message.messages);` instead of push? Since `message.messages` is also an array.

Comment: Never used concat tbh. I just read about it and used it. No difference. Now it's not even displaying the distorted view I was getting before. Is it because message.messages is an array of objects?

Comment: if both `$scope.message[i].messages` and `message.messages` are array of messages, then doing push doesn't make sense. You need to merge both like `$scope.message[i].messages = $scope.message[i].messages.concat(message.messages)`. Notice that you need to assign the result unlike push.

Comment: Well I know what you are referring to. Here's the deal, $scope.message contains array of threads. Now the message is an array of objects nested inside the object thread. Messages has messagebody, author, created properties nested. I tried your second approach as well. Still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're just missing the assignment in your socket on function. Based on the rest of the code, I'd assume you want to assign the incoming message to $scope.message.

Comment: $scope.message is an array of objects. It contains all the threads. On my schema I have nested array of objects in thread schema as messages. And in the Socket on function what I'm getting is just the thread that's being updated. Are you saying I should just assign that object(in Socket on) to the scope.message array?

Comment: Tried that though. I am not getting anything in the view now. Not even the blank image

Answer (score 0):

**solution** The problem was not with array push or anything. Basically I wasn't populating the user profile(image and other details). Traced it with debugger. Logs weren't giving a clue. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Update you ***Socket.on*** method with the following code

```
 //On Socket message on update conversation
        Socket.on('UpdateConversation', function(message) {
            console.log(message);
            console.log($scope.message);
        $scope.$apply(function () {
            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.message.length; i++) {

                if ($scope.message[i]._id === message._id) {
                    $scope.message[i].messages.push(message.messages);
                }
            }
        });

        });
```